# Cannot GET /Login or later on Cannot POST /Login

Tags: html, node.js, express

pls help, was to create and submit a html form using express but Error is Cannot GET /Login   or later on Cannot POST /Login

```
<form name="myForm" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="POST" action="/login">
        Email <br><input type="email"name="email" required><br>
        Password <br><input type="Password"name="password" required><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Login">
        <input type="reset"><br>
        New to Soft Mak Finder? <a href="/Register">Register</a>
    </form>
```

Cannot POST / error using express

And here is my js code:

```
const path = require('path')
const express = require('express');
const app = express();              // to link html files from any other section
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const bcrypt=require('bcrypt-nodejs');




app.use(express.static(__dirname+"/public")); 
app.get('/',(req, res)=>{
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+"/views/index.html")); 
})

app.get("/about",(req,res)=>{
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+"/views/about.html"));
});
app.get("/notice",(req,res)=>{
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+"/views/notice.html"));
});

app.post("/login",(req,res)=>{
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+"/views/login.html"));
});
app.listen(5000,console.log("Server started...."));
```

I keep getting the error "CANNOT POST /login   or CANNOT GET/login"

Answer (score 0):

I checked the code , it's running on my system

Comment: Hi, it still doesn't work for me.. Now, when I tried:         app.post("/login",(req,res)=>{
 console.log(req.body.email);
 console.log(req.body.password);
});                                                             the login page keeps on loading after submitting the input.  Any idea?